# How can I run a .jar file on azure

Tags: java, azure

I have a complicated .jar file that I need to run on azure (C# ASP.NET). On my local system, I simply run java.exe and pass it the jar as an argument. I would like to do the same on the server, however, I don't know where java.exe is located.

I have had a look at the environment variables and found many jdk and jre references, so I assume it is possible.

I can not use ikvm, as the jar is too complex that it isn't running correctly.

So, as a summary: Where is the java.exe located on azure? And if it's not (and I can't do this), what else can I do?

EDIT:

To clarify more: I am developing a web app using ASP.NET. I have a .jar file that I have to run, and on the local machine I run it using:

```
 processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java");
 processStartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
 //more options
 Process process = new Process();
 process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;

 process.Start();
 process.WaitForExit();
```

Now I am publishing this website to Microsoft's azure services, and I would like to do the same thing. Except, running it as is tells me that the process can't be run (ie they don't understand what "java" is). I want to find a way to be able to call java as a process. Obviously, if I know the path to java.exe, I simply run the path as a command and I'll be done (ie it'll execute java). That's what I need help with.

Comment: What "azure"? AzureVM, Azure WorkerRole, Azure WebRole?

Answer (score 3):

As derpirscher mentions in the comment you haven't specified what type of Azure service you want to use, and you haven't specified the nature of your Java code (does it listen for incoming connections on some port? does it talk to any external services? etc.). More info would help us give you a better answer.

That said... one option to start with would be Azure Web Jobs, which allow you to upload and run (among other options) a Java .jar file:

[Azure Web Jobs overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/)

As the info at that link indicates, you can run on-demand, continuously, or on a periodic schedule. Some additional details found here:

[Executing Java Web Jobs on Azure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/04/28/executing-java-web-jobs-on-azure/)

For more general information about both running Java code on Azure and also interacting with Azure services from within Java code, see here:

[Azure Java Dev Center](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/java/)

Specifically, here are some additional deployment options beyond Web Jobs:

[Deploying Java code on Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/java/#deploy)

Best of luck!

EDIT based on your additional feedback:

So if I'm understanding, you want to invoke a Java .jar file by spawning a new process from an ASP.NET application when a user inputs a certain query, etc.?

I can think of two potential options:

1. Host your ASP.NET application and the .jar on an Azure virtual machine that you customize with the correct version of Java, etc. This would allow you to configure Java how you like, on what path you want, etc.
2. Decouple the resources used to host your ASP.NET application from those used to invoke the Java code by (for instance) hosting your site as an Azure Web App and writing a message from there to an Azure storage queue each time the Java code should execute. On the receiving side of the queue, you'd have an Azure Web Job configured to listen on that queue and execute your .jar file whenever a new message arrives.

[Triggering a Web Job from an Azure Queue](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to/#trigger)

In general option 2 will be preferable from a scalability and pure design standpoint (allows you to separate the concerns of accepting queries vs. processing them, align costs most directly with actual resource consumption, etc.) but option 1 is perhaps easier from the perspective of someone unfamiliar with Azure or cloud architecture.

Just know that, depending on the nature of the processing you have to perform, number of expected concurrent users, etc. an acceptable VM-based solution may be more expensive than something similar to option 1 above. Like so many things in cloud, its ultimately a time vs. expense tradeoff that you have to make here.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for the reply. These don't exactly fit my needs (as I run the applet based on input from users, so it runs everytime a certain query is given, etc). I updated the question to be more specific, maybe now you can give me the answer I'm looking for :)?

Answer (score 3):

Assumption that your application in C#/ASP.NET was running on Azure App Service like Azure WebApp. So you can access the Kudu console via the url `https://<your-webapp-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`, then you can command `cd ..\"Program Files (x86)"\Java` to move to the path of the collection of Java SDKs for different versions.

Please try to use the absolute path for `java.exe` (like `D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk<version\\bin\\java.exe>`) as the argument for the C# Class `ProcessStartInfo`.

However, I still recommend that you could try to deploy the application using Azure VM and run the app via configure the related environment variables on VM.